# EPPlus ломает xlsx таблицы

Tags: c#, xlsx, epplus

Собственно при применении вот этого кода либы EPPlus, таблица ломается. Я после изменения загружаю таблицу на сервера яндекса, где она уже не может открыться. Если убрать изменение таблица в цикле, и её сохранение, то она не повреждается. Как быть?

```
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(localPath, FileMode.Open)) {
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    ExcelPackage table = new ExcelPackage(file);
    string[] data = Console.ReadLine().Split('/');
    ExcelWorksheet sheet = table.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
        string[] parames = data[i].Split(';');
        sheet.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = parames[0];
        sheet.Cells[i + 2, 5].Value = parames[1];
        sheet.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = parames[2];
    }

    table.Save();
    web.UploadData(disk.GetResourceUploadLink(diskPath, true).Href, "PUT", table.GetAsByteArray());
    web.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: А локальный файл после изменений нормально открывается?

Comment: Проверить не могу, но я уже NPIO использовал, там нормально

Answer (score 0):

Я подозреваю, что дело в том, что вы вызываете `table.Save()` уже за пределами `using` `FileStream'а` , а сам `EPPlus` пользуется потоком для сохранения результатов.

В этом случае загадка, как оно будет работать:

Если поток не соберется сборщиком в момент сохранения, то скорее всего сохранится нормально, в противном случае вы получите битый файл, так как что-то не дописывается.

Если вы  хотите сохранить через другой `Steam`, то есть метод `SaveTo`

Я обычно наоборот в `using` обрамляю `ExcelPackage`, а внутрь передаю созданный поток.